# Creating, Deleting and Accessing columns in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe `df` and thought I could also create a new column by doing:

```
df.Age = 4
```

This did not work, as I only gave the dataframe an attribute `Age` and assigned it the number `4`

Also, when I tried `df.head()`, the output did not show a `Age` column either.

So I wonder if there is a way to delete `Age` from the dataframe and how do I actually create a column `Age` in my dataframe, filled with only `4`'s ?

Comment: See [here](https://github.com/pydata/pandas/issues/7175), apparently you can't assign a new column through dot notation, so you should do something like `df['Age'] = 4` instead.

Comment: Do you happen to know how I can delete that item?

Comment: `del df.Age` should do it, but ideally you would just rerun your script from the start without the attempted assignment. Always best with data stuff to have all your data transformation steps saved in a script and just recreate all steps starting from the raw data whenever you start a new session, IMO.

Comment: Thanks, it worked. If you want, you can list your second comment as an answer and i will accept it. Thanks

Comment: The dot notation implies an attribute for your dataframe, it becomes ambiguous as to whether you are trying to add a new attribute to your dataframe (we can ignore the fact this is a dataframe but any python class object that supports `__dict__`) or you are adding a new column. Also see this: http://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/indexing.html#attribute-access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways of accessing columns in a DataFrame.
By:

1. Dot notation ( `df.column_name` )
2. List accessor ( `df['column_name']` )

The *dot notation* is only usable for reading and modifying existing columns, **cannot be used for creating new columns**.

If you want to create a new column, you have to use the *list accessor*

`df['Age'] = 4` will create a new column `'Age'` where all elements are `4`

After doing this you can update this column using `df.Age = 6`, but not before.

Deleting an existing column is done by the python native `del` keyword.

`del df.Age` will **not** work for columns, as this is an attribute accessor. It will however work if you have *created an attribute on the DataFrame object*

`del df['Age']` will delete the column `'Age'` if it is a column, not an attribute